# Are there reasons to prefer a function template declaration with specializations over regular function overloading?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, overloading

Is there any case where

```
template<typename T>
return_type f(T t);

template<>
return_type f<type1>(type1 t)
{ /* ... */ }

template<>
return_type f<type2>(type2 t)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Over

```
return_type f(type1 t)
{ /* ... */ }

return_type f(type2 t)
{ /* ... */ }
```

Where `return_type`, `type1`, and `type2` are plain typenames in the context of `f`.

I would say the former is needless use of templates, but at least on [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl), this is used as an example, even though the specialized templates or overloaded functions give the same working result. So I wonder, am I missing something?

Comment: There're some subtle differences; but for this case they have same result.

Comment: Some IDEs may not show a right function definition when you click "Show Definition" in case of templates. It works more or less well with overloading.

Comment: Only reason I can think of is that the template allows you to have a default implementation for all types.

Comment: As an example, you cannot use template functions with other template functions and expects deduction to work properly (see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QZCNABTtO75kSRBL) for a snippet). Could it be a good reason for you?